# Quick way to add oxford comma in Microsoft PPT?

Tags: ms-access, nlp, powerpoint

Thinking out loud here - would be great if there were a button in PowerPoint that went through every text box / piece of text in the PowerPoint deck and add Oxford commas (or remove). How might this work?

(New to SO, apologies if this is an incorrect way of asking this question!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking there is. The search and replace function is activated with `Ctrl + L` or in the command bar at the right. You just need to say enter the comma and replace it with a point or nothing when you want to remove it.

Comment: Yep that makes sense, but what about the other way around? Where there are no commas, I want to add the Oxford commas.

Comment: Easy. the Oxford comma is put after 'and, or, not' , you only need to search for those and replace them for the same word plus a comma. Search and replace will look for everything and you can just click on search next to see if needs the comma or not and click to change, then go next.

Comment: You are welcome.  If the answer was satisfactory you can accept it. And remember that search and replace also exists in google docs if you need to use it on them, and in there you can also have conditions as to search for partial text too.